# How to style TabNavigator's Tabs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have such an ugly looking default Tabs for TabNavigator. How can I add styles on it **like Instagram**?

[image]

I want to set the Tabs Navigator's background as `white` (not grey) and set the border's top with line. Plus, I want to set the active icon color as black. (JUST LIKE THE INSTAGRAM..!)

I'm not sure where I can put these styles on my TabNavigator.

```
export default TabNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: FeedStackNavigator,
    },
    ...
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
       header: null,
       tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
           const { routeName } = navigation.state;
           let iconName;
           switch (routeName) {
               case 'Feed':
                   iconName = Platform.OS === 'ios'
                   ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
              : 'md-list-box';
            break;
  }
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-navigation has lots of different [properties for styling](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOptions-for-TabBarBottom-default-tab-bar-on-iOS) `TabNavigator`. You can use them to style your icons and `TabBar` itself.

**Example**

```
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
}
```